# R　目的変数は基準化する？

Tags: r

Rを使って重回帰分析を行う時に、説明変数間のバラつきをとりのぞき一定にするために基準化（平均を0、分散を1に）をしますが、この時目的変数に対しても基準化してしまってよいのですか？
良いかどうか、またその理由をお教えいただきたいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

基準化（標準化）するということは，回帰式（目的変数と説明変数の直接的な関係式）ではなく標準偏回帰係数（各説明変数の寄与度）を知りたいわけですよね？

であれば，定数項を残したくないので，目的変数も標準化すべきだと思いますよ．